Standard UTType for Word Docs with UIDocumentPickerViewController?
I'm updating some old code to avoid deprecated stuff and to use new APIs with UIDocumentPickerViewController. I used to have to list a bunch of custom strings for various file types like so:
NSArray<NSString*> *types = @[
    (__bridge NSString *)kUTTypePDF,
    (__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeText,
    
    @"com.microsoft.word.doc",
    @"org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document",
    
    @"com.microsoft.excel.xls",
    @"org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    
    @"com.microsoft.powerpoint.ppt",
    @"org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation",
    
    @"com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages",
    @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.sffnumbers",
    @"com.apple.keynote.key",
    
    @"public.zip-archive",
];

UIDocumentPickerViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];

But I want to use the newer -initForOpeningContentTypes and use UTType which has many more built-in types that also cover lots of forms of those types. For example, instead of having to declare com.microsoft.excel.xls and org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet in order to cover xls and xlsx files, I can just declare:
NSArray<UTType*> *types = @[
    UTTypePDF,
    UTTypeText,
    UTTypePresentation,
    UTTypeSpreadsheet,
    UTTypeZIP,
    [UTType typeWithIdentifier:@"com.microsoft.word.doc"],
    [UTType typeWithIdentifier:@"org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"],
    [UTType typeWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages"],
];

UIDocumentPickerViewController *picker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initForOpeningContentTypes:types asCopy:YES];

However, I cannot find a built-in UTType that will cover "word processing documents" like doc, docx, and pages. As far as I can tell, I still need to use raw string constants for those, but I'm hoping there is a built-in type I can use and maybe I'm just missing it in the documentation.
Is there a word-processing doc UTType that covers doc, docx, pages, etc, similar to how UTTypeSpreadsheet covers xls, xlsx, numbers, etc?

All of the types are listed in the docs.  Maybe https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uniformtypeidentifiers/uttype/3551579-text ?

Just typeWithFilenameExtension: doesn't work?

@Cy-4AH I'm not sure you understand the point. I know how I can force it to work, I'm trying to figure out if there is an -elegant- and -proper- way to make it work. Sure, I could add xls and xlsx and numbers, etc with typeWithFilenameExtension:, but I would much rather use the conceptual type of UTTypeSpreadsheet so that iOS can handle every type of spreadsheet it knows instead of just the filename extensions that I could think of at the time... and then have users screw me over by removing the file extensions from their docs or something. They've been known to do weird stuff.

@Paulw11 Yes, I know the types are listed in the docs, which is where I got the several that I referenced in the original question (and I already included UTTypeText in my accepted types, but when I include UTTypeText it doesn't match against Word Docs). I couldn't find anything for document types in the list and that seemed like a weird oversight since there was a UTType for Spreadsheet and Presentation. That's why I was asking here, because maybe I missed something in the UTType documentation.

No, there are no common identifiers among the word processing file formats, except the very general public.item, public.content etc.
You can view the UTType "tree" using the mdls command. These are the results for .doc, .docx, .pages:
% mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree foo.pages
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.apple.iwork.pages.sffpages",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content"
)
% mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree foo.docx
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document",
    "org.openxmlformats.openxml",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content"
)
% mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree foo.doc
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.microsoft.word.doc",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content"
)

Spreadsheets on the other hand, have public.spreadsheet in common:
% mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree foo.numbers 
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "com.apple.iwork.numbers.sffnumbers",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content",
    "public.spreadsheet"
)
% mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree foo.xlsx 
kMDItemContentTypeTree = (
    "org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "org.openxmlformats.openxml",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content",
    "public.spreadsheet"
)

